# Ransack, search multiple columns, one field, rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, ransack

I'm new to Ruby on Rails, and I'm creating my first site. I have a user model with 3 columns: `firstname`, `lastname` and `email`. Im using ransack to make a search engine, and i want to have one search field that will go through every column and display the result.

I have made a **user_controller.rb** looking like this:

```
@q = User.search(params[:q])
@users = @q.result(:distinct => true)
```

And my **User\index.html.erb** looks like this:

```
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :firstname_cont , "Firstname" %>
    <%= f.text_field :firstname_cont %>
    <%= f.label :lastname_cont , "Lastname" %>
    <%= f.text_field :lastname_cont %>
    <%= f.label :email_cont , "Email" %>
    <%= f.text_field :email_cont %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Search" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Giving me 3 search fields, but i only want one that goes through firstname, lastname and email.

Edit 1 : 
After testing some more, I found out that the search field can't handle both firstname AND lastname, or any whitespaces. I have read that it is possible to make a helper_method like this: 
[Searching multiple fields with Ransack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309062/searching-multiple-fields-with-ransack/13311237#13311237)

And when I get the search result I get thrown into my model index etc: user / index. Where can I change this?

But there is nothing on how to use it in the view. Why is it so hard to just whrigt, this is what you do :in Controller do this -> in model do this -> in view do this -> And dont forget to fixs the routes like this ->

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First of all, before asking try to search a bit through the gem docs and googling a bit ^_^.

The first one to refer is the github page : https://github.com/ernie/ransack

Looking at the **demo page** of Ransack here : http://ransack-demo.herokuapp.com/ you should see the first field  does what you want (search in both in lastname and firsname) and having a look at the source code of the page you should see this line

```
<input id="q_first_name_or_last_name_cont" name="q[first_name_or_last_name_cont]" size="30" type="text" />
```

which gives you an idea on the **correct predicate** to use, you can also have a list of them here : https://github.com/ernie/ransack/blob/master/lib/ransack/constants.rb (always in the gem doc on github).

Based on that you can do something like that in your view

```
<%= f.text_field :lastname_or_first_name_or_email_cont, :placeholder => 'full name or email contains' %>
```

that generates a 'OR condition' query, as you can see in the demo page again (where the query generated is dispayed as a traditional SQL query)

Hope this helps

Cheers

Comment: Can i ask you for some more help? I have noticed that whitespace, or searching with more then 1 word will make this method to fail. Like if firstname is Foo, and lastname is Bar, and i search Foo bar, it will fail.. Is it possible to build a : def set_full_name .... end, and then call it in the view? and how do you call it in the view? with helper_method? i dident manage to do this.. And one last thing, if i have search any other place, my results will allways throw me to the model - index. Why is this?

Comment: Hi Remi, I'm facing the same wall about searching with multiple words in the search field and did not find any answer at the moment. You can probably use a ransacker to build a 'virtual column' to search on, there's an example here https://github.com/ernie/ransack_demo/blob/master/app/models/user.rb. 2nd part of your question, the results always throws you to the model-index because in the 'search' action of your controller you render the 'index' view. Cheers

Comment: Nice, thank you! I will take a closer look at that demo. Im still learing RoR on my own, and trawling the web for information.

Comment: what if i want to search for last_name(string) or id(integer)?

Comment: @Leo - why would you want to search for ID? From a user perspective ID should normally be kept invisible....

Comment: BTW, is it possible to say that you want the results sorted in some kind of relevance? Exmaple: in this case, first the results that match the "firstname" and then, "lastname"?